# Get full file path (without alias) on Lion in Java

Tags: java, file, path, osx-lion

I have a file with the absolute path: **/Users/ivan/test.txt**

```
String absolutePath = file.getAbsolutePath();
```

But I need the full path: **/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/ivan/test.txt** ("/" is an alias of "Macintosh HD").

I have already tried using getCanonicalPath and FileSystemView but I always get the same path.

Comment: Why exactly do you need `/Volumes/Macintosh HD`?

Comment: @ThomasMueller Because I need to know the volume of the files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I did it using Runtime (I only needed the real name folder of the "/" alias in the volume folder:

```
...
// ls -al command lists the files and the alias
proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ls -al /Volumes");

BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new 
InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));

String line;
// match the name between the time and the arrow
Pattern myPatter = Pattern.compile("[0-9]+:[0-9]+ (.*?) -> " + "/");
Matcher matcher;
while ((line = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
        if (line.indexOf(" -> ") != -1){
            // get the real volume name                    
            matcher = myPatter.matcher(line);
            if (matcher.find())
                return matcher.group(1);                     
        }                    
}
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [Aliases.h](http://opensource.apple.com/source/CarbonHeaders/CarbonHeaders-8A428/Aliases.h) file.  Specifically, you want to look at the functions `FSIsAliasFile()` and `FSResolveAlias` family of functions, possibly `FSResolveAlias()` or `FSResolveAliasFile()`.

I haven't tried this myself, but it looks like something that should give you what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no way to get that path with pure Java. Yiou'll have to write a native shared-object.

Maye there are some imporvements with Java-7 and the [FileSystem](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileSystem.html)